# React Natice Expo with Sanity receive TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_sanity.default.fetch') error

Tags: react-native, expo, sanity

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_sanity.default.fetch')

sanity.js file

```
import client from '@sanity/client';
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';

export const sanityClient = client({
    projectId: '2hjc0jso',
    dataset: 'production',
    useCdn: true,
    apiVersion: '2021-10-21',
});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);
export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
```

HomeScreen.js File fetch part

```
import sanityClient from '../sanity';

const HomeScreen = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [featuredCategories, setFeaturedCategories] = useState([]);

useLayoutEffect(() => {
   navigation.setOptions({
       headerShown: false,
   });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    sanityClient.fetch('*[_type == "featured"] {...,restaurants[] -> {...,dishes[]->, } }')   
    .then((result) => {
       setFeaturedCategories(date);
     }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
     });
}, []);
```

When removing below part of the code removes the error, but i'm unable to fetch data from sanity cms

```
sanityClient.fetch(
    `*[_type == "featured"] {...,restaurants[] -> {...,dishes[]->, } }`).then((result) => {
         setFeaturedCategories(date);
    }).catch((err) => {
       console.log(err);
});`
```